# Unable to cast object of type 'MessageBodyStream' to type 'System.IO.MemoryStream'

Tags: c#, wcf

I am returning a memorystream in the form of a Stream from my wcf server.
When I retrieve that in the client and cast it back to MemoryStream,I get this error.

I don't understand from where MessageBodyStream came from as I never used it.Can someone please tell me a solution for this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: The error is "Unable to cast object of type 'MessageBodyStream' to type 'System.IO.MemoryStream'". Thats the error on the client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/097e0a22-1be0-4250-8b1b-b49c3eb9d3bd) suggests, that you need to read this stream into your MemoryStream first, if you want to access it as MemoryStream.  Because [any stream you send is received as MessageBodyStream](https://web.archive.org/web/20110119000721/http://christopherdeweese.com/blog2/post/streaming-in-wcf-knowing-is-half-the-battle).

Comment: Thanks, I found the same forum post on google just now now and refreshed the page here to see your reply with the same link :)

Answer (score 7):

Why not use it as a [`Stream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.aspx) instead of a `MemoryStream`?

You may want to read [this](http://christopherdeweese.com/blog2/post/streaming-in-wcf-knowing-is-half-the-battle) blog post, which specifically mentions the behavior you're seeing:

> For example, if you send a
>   MemoryStream, the receiver will
>   receive it as the
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.StreamFormatter.MessageBodyStream
>   class (any stream you send is received
>   as this).

http://christopherdeweese.com/blog2/post/streaming-in-wcf-knowing-is-half-the-battle

Here's some MSDN info on the topic: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx

Comment: @Josh, glad that it helped. But why didn't you accept this as answer in that case? zespri posted the answer 14 minutes later with the same link I already posted...

Answer (score 2):

`MessageBodyStream` and `MemoryStream` are unrelated types, you cant cast one to the other. You should propably just use the returned object as a [`Stream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.aspx).